# How to pass Ruby variable's value from a Ruby page to a Ruby template

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have a Ruby files structure like this:

- app.rb
- /views/index.erb
- /views/layout.erb

app.rb is the main app file that contains the routes. Let's say I have one route as this:

```
get "/" do
  erb :index
end
```

In layout.erb I have my html head and closing `</body>` and `</html>` and etc. It is also where I have `<head>..</head>` and where I can put that scope for some JavaScript methods.

Let's say now that I have my Ruby logic in index.erb. I get a value somehow from my logic (index.erb) and I want to pass that value to my layout.erb. Is it possible? If so, how we do that?

I have checked the @variable_name to pass it as argument from the route definition:

```
get "/" do
  @variable_name = ??? -> this do not works since I did not get the logic yet from index.erb, no?
  erb :index
end
```

I also have tried to use simply <%= variable_name %> or #{variable_name} directly in the layout.erb but without any success.

Comment: Why is there logic in the view layer?

Comment: Because I have put some JavaScript there... in the <head>..</head> section. I am trying to pass a value calculated from index.erb into that template. But now that you ask, I can create a custom template for that specific page and put the JavaScript in, let's say, index.erb then!

Comment: What does JavaScript have to do with Ruby code? If you're doing stuff in JavaScript you've already sent the result to the browser, the server-side code is done running unless you make an Ajax request.

Comment: I am new to Ruby so please excuse myself if I do not use it completely properly yet! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out that I was able to transport my "code" to view the widgets I wanted to populated in the index.erb so by that I resolve my problem of accessing the value that was define from a variable declared in index.erb.

Problem solved and a better way to work with Ruby as this issue makes me read more about how to structure myself (Thx to Dave).